# TFS: Wix using TfvcTemplate.12 unable to find source files

Tags: tfs, msbuild, wix

I need to use TfvcTemplate.12.xaml because of its Pre and Post build script execution support and I need to run a Powershell script as PreBuild event.

On TFS 2013, Building a Wix project using old DefaultTemplate.xaml works fine. While trying to build using new default template TfvcTemplate.12.xaml builds the csharp project fine, but Wix is unable to find its files, while files are present at same location.

Here is Wix code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?define SourceDir=$(var.OutDir)?>
  <?warning **************** Target=$(var.TargetDir) ***********?>
  <?warning **************** src=$(var.SourceDir) **************?>
    <Product Id="*" Language="1033" Manufacturer="Test" Name="Testing" UpgradeCode="DB7DAC5A-ED29-45E6-8029-89F6486A9ACA" Version="1.0.0.0">
        <Package Compressed="yes" InstallerVersion="200" Platform="x64" />
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="ProgFiles">
            <Directory Id="bin" Name="bin">
                <Component Id="AddProjToSln.exe" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="AddProjToSln.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)AddProjToSln.exe" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="AddProjToSln.exe.config" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="AddProjToSln.exe.config" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)AddProjToSln.exe.config" />
                </Component>
               </Directory>
        </Directory>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Level="1" Title="TestFe">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="Testing" />
        </Feature>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="product.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Testing">
            <ComponentRef Id="AddProjToSln.exe" />
            <ComponentRef Id="AddProjToSln.exe.config" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Here is the log from TFS:

> Build started 10/13/2014 5:24:15 PM.
>        1>Project "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln.sln"
>   on node 1 (default targets).
>        1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
>            Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
>        1>Project "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln.sln"
>   (1) is building
>   "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln\AddProjToSln.csproj"
>   (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>        2>PrepareForBuild:
>            Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
>        1>Project "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln.sln"
>   (1) is building
>   "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj"
>   (3) on node 2 (default targets).
>        3>PrepareForBuild:
>            Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
>          Compile:
>            C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\candle.exe -dDebug -d"DevEnvDir=*Undefined if not building from within Visual Studio*"
>   -dSolutionDir=D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\
>   -dSolutionExt=.sln -dSolutionFileName=AddProjToSln.sln -dSolutionName=AddProjToSln -dSolutionPath=D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln.sln
>   -dConfiguration=Debug -dOutDir=D:\Builds\31\47\bin\ -dPlatform=x86 -dProjectDir=D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\
>   -dProjectExt=.wixproj -dProjectFileName=test_install.wixproj -dProjectName=test_install -dProjectPath=D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj
>   -dTargetDir=D:\Builds\31\47\bin\ -dTargetExt=.msi -dTargetFileName=test.msi -dTargetName=test -dTargetPath=D:\Builds\31\47\bin\test.msi -out obj\Debug\ -arch x86 Product.wxs
>        3>D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(4):
>   warning CNDL1096: **************** Target=D:\Builds\31\47\bin\
>   *********** [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>        3>D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(5):
>   warning CNDL1096: **************** src=D:\Builds\31\47\bin\
>   ************** [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>          Link:
>            C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\Light.exe -out D:\Builds\31\47\bin\test.msi -pdbout D:\Builds\31\47\bin\test.wixpdb
>   -cultures:null -contentsfile obj\Debug\test_install.wixproj.BindContentsFileListnull.txt
>   -outputsfile obj\Debug\test_install.wixproj.BindOutputsFileListnull.txt
>   -builtoutputsfile obj\Debug\test_install.wixproj.BindBuiltOutputsFileListnull.txt
>   -wixprojectfile D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj
>   obj\Debug\Product.wixobj
>        2>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>          Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input
>   files.
>        3>D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(12):
>   error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file
>   'D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.exe'.
>   [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>        3>D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(15):
>   error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file
>   'D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.exe.config'.
>   [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>        3>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.
>        2>CoreCompile:
>            C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU
>   /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /main:AddProjToSln.Program /highentropyva+
>   /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\envdte.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\envdte100.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\envdte80.dll" /reference:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\envdte90.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize-
>   /out:obj\Debug\AddProjToSln.exe /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe
>   /utf8output /win32icon:"Crystal_Clear_mimetype_recycled (2).ico"
>   Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
>   "C:\Users\tfsbuild\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>          _CopyAppConfigFile:
>            Copying file from "App.config" to "D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.exe.config".
>          CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
>            Copying file from "obj\Debug\AddProjToSln.exe" to "D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.exe".
>            AddProjToSln -> D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.exe
>            Copying file from "obj\Debug\AddProjToSln.pdb" to "D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.pdb".
>        2>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln\AddProjToSln.csproj"
>   (default targets).
>        1>Done Building Project "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln.sln"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> ```
>    "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln.sln"
> ```
>
> (default target) (1) ->
>          "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj"
>   (default target) (3) ->
>          (Compile target) -> 
>            D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(4):
>   warning CNDL1096: **************** Target=D:\Builds\31\47\bin\
>   *********** [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>            D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(5):
>   warning CNDL1096: **************** src=D:\Builds\31\47\bin\
>   ************** [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>
> ```
>    "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\AddProjToSln.sln"
> ```
>
> (default target) (1) ->
>          "D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj"
>   (default target) (3) ->
>          (Link target) -> 
>            D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(12):
>   error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file
>   'D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.exe'.
>   [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>            D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\Product.wxs(15):
>   error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file
>   'D:\Builds\31\47\bin\AddProjToSln.exe.config'.
>   [D:\Builds\31\47\src\MyComp\Playground\MyUser\Utilities\VisualStudio\TestInstall\test_install.wixproj]
>
> ```
> 2 Warning(s)
> 2 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.04

I verified multiple times that files are there and it builds without any problem at command line using MsBuild and Wix Tool set as well.

I'm unable to figure out why using TfvcTemplate.12.xaml, wix is unable to see its files while these are present intact there....

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: why -1? what's wrong with this situation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, finally I was able to solve this after a whole day struggle. Like Digg a mountain and got a mice :).

Actually TfvcTemplate.12.xaml seems to be executing MsBuild with parallel processing enabled (/m), while in my VS Solution, Wix project was added independently i.e. in Build Order it was the last project to build, but I never set other projects as its dependencies. So MSBuild found that it has no dependency and ignored its Build Order and simply building it either on random order or as first project. So naturally installer project was unable to find its source files and so failing.

I verified this phenomena by removing /m:1 argument to MSBuild and declaring all other projects as Dependencies of Wix Project: i.e. in VS, PROJECT –> Project Dependencies. This caused MsBuild to build all other projects before Wix Project and now Wix is able to find its Source files properly…

Here is the screenshot for illustration: 
[image: Forcing linear processing in TfvcTemplate]